# strange regex ungreedy behavior

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to understand why the following regex:`\/.+?.ext\/` is not working as exptected in the following sentence:`http://slash1/slash2/slash3.ext/slash4`.

Indeed, I'm only interested in matching the part of the url having the '.ext' extension.
I first though adding the ungreedy character would reduce the scope to the closer backslash, but it is not the case, it actually match: `//slash1/slash2/slash3.ext/`

here is the link to test it: http://rubular.com/r/CjJZFssQRF

**EDIT:**
Just in case someone else land here, I finally ended up using the following regex:`[^\/]+?\.ext`
updated rubular:http://rubular.com/r/FKcBQI50Lm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches everything between the **first** slash it encounters and `ext`. This explains your match.

You have two possibilities now. You can either go for look-arounds, which are more complicated, or you simply disallow slashes to be matched between two slashes:

```
\/[^\/]+?\.ext\/
```

(note: I escaped the dot that is part of the extension, otherwise it would match `slash3aext`)

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kL3vW3)

I'm just taking a guess here, but I think you "thought" from right to left (`when i encounter .ext i want everything until i encounter a slash to the left`), when you're supposed to think from left to right, just as a regex examines your string.

Comment: You were right, it was exactly how I was thinking. thx for pointing that up.

Comment: @gomino For the non-effective `?`: you may read about this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Basically the `+` will match **as many** characters as possible before satisfying the next token (`\.ext`), while `+?` will match **as few** characters as possible (but everytime minimum one! For zero to unlimited you'd use `*`).

Comment: Why did you take off the . before the lazy + i.e `\/[^\/]+?\.ext\/` instead of `\/[^\/].+?\.ext\/`

Comment: The `.` matches every character (except newline). The `[]` denotes a character class, everything inside will be matched. `^` negates the character class, so everything inside can't match. In other words: `[^\/]+` means: `match every character except /` (in contrast to the `.`: `match every character`). I strongly suggest you try to read up on regexes (for example [here](http://regular-expression.info)), as character classes are one of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
\/[^\/]+?.ext\/
```

The regex engine works from the very first character and will keep attempting to match with your expression for each subsequent character. That's just how regular expressions are executed. Think of it like this

```
^.*?\/[^\/]+?\.ext\/.*$
```

Comment: I am more trying to understand the reason why the ungreedy '?' character is not working in that specific case. There is no need for it in your solution `\/[^\/]+?.ext\/` is equivalent to `\/[^\/]+.ext\/`